# How to list all currently targeted hosts in an Ansible play

Tags: ansible

I am running an Ansible play and would like to list all the hosts targeted by it. Ansible docs [mentions that this is possible](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once), but their method doesn't seem to work with a complex targeted group (targeting like hosts: web_servers:&data_center_primary)

I'm sure this is doable, but cant seem to find any further documentation on it. Is there a var with all the currently targeted hosts?

Comment: Not sure to which section you're referring to in the docs. (maybe wrong link?) - If you didn't mean/know it, you can use the switch `--list-hosts` to only list hosts a playbook would affect.

Comment: --list-hosts is the data I want, but for a specific play, with different targeting than the overall input

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You are looking for 'play_hosts' variable

```
---
- hosts: all

  tasks:
    - name: Create a group of all hosts by app_type
      group_by: key={{app_type}}

    - debug: msg="groups={{groups}}"
      run_once: true

- hosts: web:&some_other_group

  tasks:
   - debug: msg="play_hosts={{play_hosts}}"
     run_once: true
```

would result in

```
TASK: [Create a group of all hosts by app_type] *******************************
changed: [web1] => {"changed": true, "groups": {"web": ["web1", "web2"], "load_balancer": ["web3"]}}

TASK: [debug msg="play_hosts={{play_hosts}}"] *********************************
ok: [web1] => {
    "msg": "play_hosts=['web1']"
}
```

inventory:

```
[proxy]
web1 app_type=web
web2 app_type=web
web3 app_type=load_balancer

[some_other_group]
web1
web3
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, Thank you! Did you just know this from experience, or was this in the ansible docs somewhere? If in the docs could you link?

Comment: Well, I did find it by reading either ansible google-groups https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ansible-project or some playbook example (can't recall exactly)
Now when I know what am I looking for, there is a sentence about that in:
http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#id40

Comment: `play_hosts` is [depriacated from 2.2](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html). You can now use `ansible_play_batch`

Answer (score 39):

You can use the option `--list-hosts` to only list hosts a playbook would affect.

Also, there is the dict `hostvars` which holds all hosts currently known to Ansible. But I think the `setup` module had to be run on all hosts, so you can not skip that step via `gather_facts: no`.

Comment: `--check` is handy too. Neither of them (list-hosts, check) is perfect, but it's nice to know about them.

Comment: to list all hosts from the command I need to know what was the `--limit` value in ad_hoc, is there any way to get it?
`--list-hosts` is giving result to console, but i need to handle result in last task of the last playbook